# Common persons table with specific tables for teachers and students or separate tables?

Tags: postgresql, admin-on-rest, react-admin, hasura

I'm using `react-admin` with `hasura` as an API for Postgres.

I have a need for different entities that are all basically a person but with different purposes. Eg. a student and a teacher. I am thinking, given the similar attributes, it would be good to have a person table that will share common features and then have a separate tables for specific attributes. For example, tables like this:

```
persons {
    id,
    first_name,
    last_name,
    birthday
    ...
}

students {
    id,
    person_id,
    date_enrolled
    ...
}

teachers {
    id,
    person_id,
    sallary
    ...
}
```

The problem I encounter with that schema is that in order to create a student, the person for it has to be created first. So in react-admin I will have to present a user with a form for creating a person first and then another form to create a student based on that person.

I guess it's not ideal and maybe it would be better to have separate tables for `students` and `teachers` although some fields (first_name, last_name, birthday...) would be repeated in both tables.

This question is not really specific for `react-admin` but more of a general advice on similiar db model design so any tips are more than welcome :).

Comment: I am not familiar with the tools you are using, but can you create a single form with all the data needed for both tables? Internally, the software would first insert the person data and, with that, insert the student / teacher data...

Comment: I could do that, sure, but it doesn't seem easily doable with react-admin.

Answer (score 1):

This requirement is a perfect fit for PostgreSQL's [“table inheritance” feature](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-inherit.html).

You could model `student` and `teacher` as inheritance children of `person`. Then everything should work as you want. Querying `person` will return results from both tables.

Comment: Great, thanks. Didn't know about table inheritance. I am reading the docs and not sure if inserting will work...